# How to send push notification just in foreground

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I sending push notification like this from node.js server:

```
const message = {
                android: {
                    ttl: 3600 * 1000,
                    notification: {
                        icon: 'stock_ticker_update',
                        color: '#f45342',
                        sound: "notify"
                    }
                },
                token: user.deviceToken,
                ...notification
            };
return await adminCli.messaging().send(message);
```

For some push messages I would like it receive just in foreground, but not when app is running in background...
So for specific message I receive in background I want to ignore it... Is it posible to achive?

Comment: try using firebase `in-app-messaging` feature. its currently in beta. https://firebase.google.com/products/in-app-messaging/

Comment: Sounds like it's something that can be done from the client side.. I don't think it's possible to control from the server side.

Comment: How is it possible to do on the client side?

Comment: You can save the notification data when the notification is received (in the SharedPreferences for example), and when app goes back to foreground check if there is notification data and post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs:

> onMessageReceived is provided for most message types, with the following exceptions:
>
> - **Notification messages delivered when your app is in the background**. In this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray. A user tap on a notification opens the app launcher by default.
> - **Messages with both notification and data payload, both background and foreground**. In this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your launcher Activity.

So if you are using NotificationMessages you can't control the behavior when the app is in the background because it would be handled by the System Tray.

I recommend you using a DataPlayload Message and in the **onMessageReceived** method decide to show the notification or ignore it.

You can read more [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive)

### EDIT

In case it was not clear, I mean using a DATA ONLY message and not using the Notification when creating the message in your server

Comment: But ```onMessageReceived``` is only triggered in foreground... When app is background it will even not call that function...

Comment: if using Data Messages `onMessageReceived` is triggered for **every** receive message and it's your responsability to show an Android Notification or not

Comment: Take a look at the Understanding Message Payloads section in https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Sending_Firebase_Cloud_Messages_from_a_Node.js_Server